# Git : add password for pushing some files

Tags: git, repository, push, commit

Is it possible to add a password for commiting and pushing some files/folders on a GIT repository ?

Or any other way to prevent some users from commiting and pushing some files/folders they are not supposed to commit and push ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use git hooks to do what you want.  (See the git documentation at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy under the heading *Enforcing a User-Based ACL System*.)

The full example they use may be overkill for your needs; the key idea is that a post-receive hook can reject a push, so you can examine the files modified in each commit (with `git rev-list` and `git log`) and reject commits that affect certain files if that's what you want to do.

Of course this only protects the origin repo; people can do what they want locally.  But protecting the origin is really all that matters, and it's pretty much impossible to stop people from doing what they want to their local clones anyway.